# Why does chrome use excessive amounts of CPU?

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, cpu

## Synopsis

For the past few weeks, i've really started to notice a process on my machine hitting the CPU.  So today I have taken a look into it, to find that Chrome is running about 100% CPU.

- Is there any known bugs that may explain this? Or
- Is there a method for me to resolve this?

I do not have any extensions installed, it's a recent clean install with no extensions.

```
20002 ash       20   0  480848 103708  60156 S 108.9  0.9   0:03.28 chrome
```

### Chrome Version:

```
Version 40.0.2214.95 (64-bit)
```

### Ubuntu/Gnome Versions:

```
ash ~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

ash ~ $ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.10.4
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use Chrome's built-in task manager to see what part of Chrome (page, plugin, etc) is using CPU.

[image]

To access it, just press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd> (or right click the window decoration and select Task Manager)

Comment: What happens when the problem is `GPU Process` - Could this also be related to an AMD graphics card (is the only modification i have made where i've noticed a difference)?

Comment: @Ash : Did you solve the problem? Once I encountered the same issue and solved it by playing with chrome://flags but now it annoying again without any obvious reasons.

Comment: Thanks @SergeySergeyev I never know about that feature.  For me I pulled my AMD GPU out and it was still running high CPU but it's not having problems any more since i reinstalled chrome and a few updates were installed.

Comment: NOTE: I have accepted this answer because this helped me discover the problem that eventually lead to a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Switching to integrated GPU solves the high CPU issue for me.

I have the following system:

```
Graphics:  Card-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7600G]
           Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8730M]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.17.1 driver: fglrx
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.0hz, 1920x1200@60.0hz
           GLX Renderer: AMD Radeon HD 7600G
           GLX Version: 4.4.13374 - CPC 15.20.1013
```

I've switched to the Integrated GPU (instead of High Performance discrete) in Catalyst Control Center (Administrative). After reboot the high CPU in Chrome is completely gone.